# Do I have to create a new view controller every time I want to sort my data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting

I wasn't sure how to title this or even how to begin to look it up. I need some advice from you good people.  I've done some research online but all the tutorials and advice I came across perform sorts in viewDidLoad.

I have a tableview that segues to another tableview.  The first tableview is filled with a hard coded array set up something like this:

cell 0 : view list by title 
cell 1:  view list by author 
cell 2:  view list by date

After "segueing" to the second tableview, I can sort the results by EITHER title, author, OR date using NSSortDescriptor in viewDidLoad.  The way I currently have things set up, it seems like I will need to create a new view controller each time I want to sort by a certain parameter (i.e. title, author, date).  Is there a different way I can do this so I can reuse the second tableview and not have to create a new one for each kind of sort? There are more parameters than just the three I mentioned. The storyboard will get cluttered pretty quick.

The information that is being sorted comes from a custom class if that makes a difference.

Any help will be appreciated even if it turns out I have to create new view controllers every time I want to sort.  I'm just hoping there is an alternative.

Here is a code snippet from viewDidLoad:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    self.dataSource = [[self.dataSource sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil]] mutableCopy];
```

Here is code from **didSelectRow**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contentController"];

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        ListTableViewController *listController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"listController"];
        navigationController.viewControllers = @[listController];
    }

    self.frostedViewController.contentViewController = navigationController;
    [self.frostedViewController hideMenuViewController];
}
```

Comment: Try using `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` to pass your data along.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I have tried this, but haven't quite got it to work.  I have been using didSelectRowAtIndexPath to move to a new controller.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for separate view controllers. You need to pass some information to the second controller telling it which thing you want to sort by. Probably pass one of the strings, "title", "author", or "date". In the second controller, use in a if-else clause based on that passed in string to decide which way to sort, do the sort, then, reload the table.

Comment: thank you for answering and giving me hope.  I've added the code I used in viewdidload.  Would I use the if-else in viewdidload?  I have tried something like it but it seems I wasn't calling something correctly and kept getting errors.

Comment: @IWannaLearn, yes, viewDidLoad would be a good place to do it. I can't advise you further without seeing more code. How are you passing the information to the second controller, so it knows which sort to do? What is the structure of your data (I assume dataSource is an array)?

Comment: I'm using didSelectRowAtIndexPath to move to the next view controller.  I've added code above.  The sort is in viewDidLoad on the second controller.  You are correct, dataSource is an array.

Comment: @IWannaLearn, So without knowing what your app structure is, I have no idea what you're doing in didSelectRow. What controllers do you have? Where does frostedViewController fit in to the structure, and do you also have some sort of menu controller? How do you move to the second controller (And which controller is that). The code you have here doesn't actually move to a new controller.

Comment: The frosted view controller is from here: https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController.  I believe the view controllers are linked to the navigation controller rather than directly from the menu controller.  If you take a look, you'll see the base set up of my app but instead of linking from tableviewcontroller to uiviewcontroller (as in this code), my app will be linking tableviewcontroller to tableviewcontroller.  When I had played with this setup before, I made a new view controller for each cell in the menuController. I was hoping there was an easier way.